# Get custom option_id and option_type_id from custom option sku

Tags: custom-options

I would like to fetch results of the query below without using direct sql. Is it possible?
thanks

```
SELECT option_type_id, option_id FROM `catalog_product_option_type_value` optv left join catalog_product_option opt on optv.option_id=opt.option_id WHERE optv.sku='option-sku'  and opt.product_id=$product_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should give you the select you want, apart from it will perform an inner join on the product option table but that is ok as you need an entry in that table to have an entry in the option value table.

```
$optionCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')->getCollection();
$optionCollection->addFieldToSelect(array('sku', 'main.option_id'));
$optionCollection->addFieldToFilter('sku', 'option-sku');
$optionCollection->addFieldToFilter('opt.product_id', 123);
$optionCollection->join(array('opt' => 'catalog/product_option'), 'main_table.option_id = opt.option_id');
```